# Using "pip install --platform" to install .so on windows

Tags: python, pip

In the help for `pip -install` I noticed the install option --platform  -> "*Only use **wheels** compatible with platform. Defaults to the platform of the running system.*"

I was thinking I could use this option to get the Linux binaries on my windows machine however I cannot seem to get it to work as expected.

What is the proper syntax for this option, and what exactly is a "Wheel"?

`pip install --platform ubuntu --only-binary=:all: cryptography`

Returns Errors:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for cryptography

**Edit:** 
Thanks for the initial responses.  When trying to install the linux .so files on a windows machine I am getting the same errors when using various versions of the command

```
pip install --platform linux_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: cryptography
```

In the cryptography document it identifies various linux supported distributions. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/

Does anyone know how to get cryptography .so files using a windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

A [Wheel](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) is a pre-built distribution format that provides faster installation compared to Source Distributions (sdist), especially when a project contains compiled extensions[[2]](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#source-distributions-vs-wheels).

I don't think `ubuntu` is a possible value for the `--platform` option. Try with something like `linux_x86_64` or `linux_i386`